# How add legend in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've written this code:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = dat$color_province)) +
  theme_void() +
  
  geom_point(data = producer, 
             aes(x = producer$MX, y = producer$MY), size = 3, col = "green", shape = 17, alpha = 0.6) +
  
  geom_point(data = distribution, 
             aes(x = distribution$MX, y = distribution$MY), size = 4.5, col = "yellow", shape = 15) +
  
  geom_point(data = retailer, 
             aes(x = retailer$MX, y = retailer$MY), size = 3, col = "slateblue", shape = 16) +
  
  geom_point(data = Demand, 
             aes(x = Demand$MX, y = Demand$MY, size = Demand$De), col = "slateblue", shape = 17, alpha = 0.7) +
  
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#ff3333", "#ffc266"),
                    name = "Situation")
```

and now I want to add a legend to identify all points in my plot. How can I do it?

Comment: Do you mean add a label for each individual data point?

Comment: @AndrewMcCartney I mean that I want to add a legend of the plot to describe the meaning of each point on the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example on some data that everyone can run, since it uses built-in datasets that come with R. Here, I made color and size be dynamic aesthetics with the name of the series, and then mapped those series values to different aesthetic values using `scale_*_manual`, where `*` are the aesthetics you want to vary by series. This generates an automatic legend. By giving each aesthetic the same name ("source" here), ggplot2 knows to combine them into one legend.

(By the way, it's unnecessary and can lead to errors to refer to variables in ggplot2 aesthetics using the form `retailer$MY`; each geom will assume the variable is within the data frame referred to with `data =`, so you can just use `MY` in that case.)

```
ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = mtcars,
             aes(x = wt, y = mpg, color = "mtcars", size = "mtcars")) +
  geom_point(data = attitude,
             aes(x = rating/20, y = complaints/3, color = "attitude", size = "attitude")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("mtcars" = "slateblue", "attitude" = "red"), name = "source") +
  scale_size_manual(values = c("mtcars" = 3, "attitude" = 4.5), name = "source")
```

[image]

Comment: unfortunately, scale_*_manual does not work, and nothing adds to the plot!